# How to add a link as reference?

Tags: bibliographies

I am trying to add the below link into my references. But when I add it as shown below, LaTeX generates the following errors:

```
\bibitem{link_latlng_00}  {\em https://gcps.desire2learn.com/d2l/lor/viewer/viewfile.d2lfile/6605/7951/global_latitude_longitude.gif}.

**errors**

! Missing } inserted.
! Extra }, or forgotten $.
! Missing $ inserted.
```

Please let me know how to fix this error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The URL string contains `_` (underscore) characters, which are interpreted by LaTeX as initiating subscript material. And, as you aren't in math mode, an error message is generated about a missing `$` sign.

To typeset the URL string correctly, I suggest you load the `url` package with the options `spaces` and `hyphens` and write the entry as

```
\bibitem{link_latlng_00}  \url{https://gcps.desire2learn.com/d2l/lor/viewer/viewfile.d2lfile/6605/7951/global_latitude_longitude.gif}
```

If the hyperref package is loaded as well, this approach should yield a clickable link to the gif file.

---

A complete MWE (minimum working example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spaces,hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} %% optional
\begin{document}

\cite{link_latlng_00}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{link_latlng_00}  \url{https://gcps.desire2learn.com/d2l/lor/viewer/viewfile.d2lfile/6605/7951/global_latitude_longitude.gif}

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you..would u please tell me how to load the url package

Comment: @Elpharaoh - I just posted a full MWE. Let me know if you have further questions.